# What is a good approach to parse a 3rd party XML using provided DTD?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, dtd

I have an XML and its DTD from a 3rd party application and we are trying to parse through the XML without much knowledge of the structure. Is there a way, I can parse through the XML using its DTD and print out the contents of the XML? If so, what is a good way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - a DTD **defines** the structure of an XML. And if you have the XML, what's stopping you from printing out the content already? You don't need a DTD for that.

Comment: Also, are you using any specific code language to do this, or are you looking for an application that will do this for you? Your question is vague.

Comment: I am looking for an application or a way by which I can parse the xml using the dtd and process/print information at the various nodes and attributes

Comment: Because this question is so broad and your looking for software recommendations instead of asking about specific code issues, I would suggest you post it in the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site instead.